# Refactor JQuery setting checkbox attribute

Tags: jquery, checkbox, refactoring

Can this code be written in a one-line format?

```
if ($('#sIsTopNav').text().trim() === 'True') {
    $('#chkIsTopNav').attr('checked','checked');
}else {
    $('#chkIsTopNav').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

TIA ..

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Don't fix what's not broken, also one liners don't always read well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#chkIsTopNav').prop('checked', $('#sIsTopNav').text().trim() === 'True')
```

**Note**:

- Removing the `checked` attribute has the same effect as setting it to `false`.
- Using `.prop()` is the current recommended way for setting properties like `checked`, `disabled` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try using [conditional (ternary) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx),

```
$('#sIsTopNav').text().trim() === 'True' ? $('#chkIsTopNav').attr('checked','checked') :  $('#chkIsTopNav').removeAttr('checked');
```